# extracting the text after certain value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract the values in a column which has text data as  below:

```
create date:1953/01/01 | first author:REAGAN RL
```

How can I extract the author name from the columns and store in a new column.
I tried the following ways:

```
df.str.extract("first author:(.*?)")
```

and

`authorname=df['EntrezUID'].apply(lambda x:x.split("first author:"))`. The second one worked.

How can I use the regualr expressions achieve the similar thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
## sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'dd':['create date:1953/01/01 | first author:REAGAN RL','create date:1953/01/01 | first author:MEGAN RL']})

## output
df['names'] = df['dd'].str.extract(r'author\:(.*)')

print(df)
                                                dd      names
0  create date:1953/01/01 | first author:REAGAN RL  REAGAN RL
1   create date:1953/01/01 | first author:MEGAN RL   MEGAN RL
```

Comment: This worked for me. Appreciate your help. Can you provide me a link on the regular expressions. What exactly \:(.*) does?

Comment: What if I want to extract the created Date? df['dd'].str.extract(r'created date\:(.*)')

Comment: @HarshaVardhan `df['dd'].str.extract(r'create date:(\S+)', expand=False)`

Comment: Thanks. This one also worked for me.  df['EntrezUID'].str.extract(r'create date\:(.*)\|').   @coldspeed , Is there any blog which explain about str.extract. What  is the use of expand=False?

Comment: @HarshaVardhan Official documentation is a nice place to start: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html